# Applying argument constraints with Spock tests

Tags: java, groovy, spock

I've got some Java classes that I've written Spock tests for. When I try to verify the exact object used in an argument, the test fails.

```
    def "all events are published to subscribers"() {
        given:
        EventSubscriber subscriber = Mock()
        when:
        subscriber.shouldRegister() >> true
        subscriber.interests() >> new HashSet<Intent>(Arrays.asList(COUNTER, GAUGE))
        publisher.subscribe(subscriber)
        def event = publisher.newEvent("test", COUNTER)
        event.start()
        def child = event.newChild("child", GAUGE)
        event.finish()
        then:
//        2 * subscriber.onCreate(event)
//        1 * subscriber.onStart(event, event.start)
//        1 * subscriber.onEnd(event, event.end)
//        1 * subscriber.onChild(event, child)
        2 * subscriber.onCreate(_)
        1 * subscriber.onStart(_, _)
        1 * subscriber.onEnd(_, _)
        1 * subscriber.onChild(_, _)
    }
```

The commented out lines fail with

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: event for
>   class: io.hypi.faf.api.EventPublisherTest
>
> at io.hypi.faf.api.EventPublisherTest.all events are published to
>   subscribers(EventPublisherTest.groovy:28)

http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/all_in_one.html#_argument_constraints seems to suggests I can just pass a value in. The first example is a string but I presume type doesn't matter.

What have I done wrong with this?

Spock: 1.3
Groovy: 2.5
groovy-test-junit5-2.5.7
JDK: 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object instances used in the interaction testing should be defined in the `given` section.

This would have work:

```
def 'all events are published to subscribers'() {
    given:
    EventSubscriber subscriber = Mock()
    subscriber.shouldRegister() >> true
    subscriber.interests() >> new HashSet<Intent>(Arrays.asList(COUNTER, GAUGE))
    publisher.subscribe(subscriber)
    def event = publisher.newEvent('test', COUNTER)
    def child = event.newChild('child', GAUGE)

    when:
    event.start()
    event.finish()

    then:
    2 * subscriber.onCreate(event)
    1 * subscriber.onStart(event, event.start)
    1 * subscriber.onEnd(event, event.end)
    1 * subscriber.onChild(event, child)
}
```

But then there will be a problem with testing of invocation of `onCreate()` and `onChild()` because these calls are then not in the `when` section and only `onStart()` and `onEnd()` can match.

I don't have your classes definitions to see details but I guess that `event.start` and `event.end` fields are initialized in `start()` and `finish()` methods and then `1 * onStart(event, event.start)` and `1 * onEnd(event, event.end)` test will not match because invocation test will be done in the phase when the `event` has different `start` and `end` values. So then only `1 * onStart(event, _)` and `1 * onEnd(event, _)` tests will only match.

---

Look on this simple example which works and is similar to your case but with the difference that the `event` instance is prepared in the `given` section and not modified in the `when` so it will pass the test:

```
class InvocationWithArgumentsSpec extends Specification {
    void 'Invocation test works with arguments other then String'() {
        given:
        def subscriber = Mock(Subscriber)
        def simplePublisher = new Publisher()
        simplePublisher.subscribe(subscriber)
        def event = new SimpleEvent(name: 'test')

        when:
        simplePublisher.fireEvent(event)

        then:
        1 * subscriber.onEvent(event)
    }
}

interface Subscriber {
    void onEvent(SimpleEvent event)
}

class Publisher {
    Subscriber subscriber

    void subscribe(Subscriber subscriber) {
        this.subscriber = subscriber
    }

    void fireEvent(SimpleEvent event) {
        subscriber.onEvent(event)
    }
}

class SimpleEvent {
    String name
}
```

---

**Update:** But there is a workaround for you. It is not so nice but it works and tests that correct events are passed into subscriber methods (I guess that `event` has something like `name`):

```
def 'all events are published to subscribers'() {
    given:
    EventSubscriber subscriber = Mock()
    subscriber.shouldRegister() >> true
    subscriber.interests() >> new HashSet<Intent>(Arrays.asList(COUNTER, GAUGE))
    publisher.subscribe(subscriber)

    when:
    def event = publisher.newEvent('test', COUNTER)
    event.start()
    event.newChild('child', GAUGE)
    event.finish()

    then:
    1 * subscriber.onCreate({ it.name == 'test' })
    1 * subscriber.onCreate({ it.name == 'child' })
    1 * subscriber.onStart({ it.name == 'test' }, !null)
    1 * subscriber.onEnd({ it.name == 'test' }, !null)
    1 * subscriber.onChild({ it.name == 'test' }, { it.name == 'child' })
}
```

Comment: Ahhhh, I didn't realise instances used in interaction mocking must be defined in the given block. I don't think there's a way to use spock to mock without changing the API and behaviour so for now I've skipped mocking and created an anonymous instance and just capture the objects and counts. 

First time using Spock for this because it's a new project I thought I'd use it for testing and mocking but will probably go back to using Mockito and spock for everything else.

Comment: Yes, it's a limitation of Spock :-( But you can try the workaround which I added into the answer now. There are arguments tested by closures.

Comment: Thanks. I like it. I'm quite keen to commit to spock, it's saved us a lot of time since we started adopting it so knowing a workaround is beneficial.

Comment: @cgrim just a quick improvement `{ e -> e.name == 'test' }` -> `{ìt.name == 'test'}` and `{ start -> start != null }` -> `!null` makes it a bit less noisy.

Comment: Thank you @LeonardBrünings I updated the answer accordingly. I'm still thinking more in Java way then Groovy way :-)